# Signal and slot for multiple widgets

Tags: c++, qt

I have three pushbutton widgets in my class and i want to connect the clicked signals from all of the three to one slot. Here is what my syntax looks like:

```
QObject::connect(PtrLineedit1, SIGNAL(Clicked()), this, SLOT(myslot()));
QObject::connect(PtrLineedit2, SIGNAL(Clicked()), this, SLOT(myslot()));
QObject::connect(PtrLineedit3, SIGNAL(Clicked()), this, SLOT(myslot()));
```

But the above syntax is not working. And the above syntax i am using in one of my WizardPage class. this Wizard has three pages, and in one of the page(class) has three pushbuttons and in this class constructor i am trying to achieve. I have used "clicked()" too, but no luck

Comment: Can you elaborate on "is not working"?

Comment: Consider rephrasing/refactoring your question. In its current form your question is not understandable.

Comment: clicked() should work and Qt supports connecting multiple signals to one slot. Check your program output. It should notify you if qt was unable to connect the signal and slots. Check if this piece of code executes (You say it's in constructor of the class that has these puchbuttons, so unless it's in an if clause it should execute)

Comment: `PtrLineedit` doesn't sound like a button... are you using the correct sender?

Comment: Sorry, its an push button but have named it wrongly, I think as I have a main wizard, which has these three pages as wizard pages, must i change the parent widget? when i try to debug, i am not able to reach and the point is getting disabled and in console too i do not get any output saying not able to connect

Answer (score 6):

First of all, there is no signal "Clicked", but there is "clicked" - the lowercase one.

Second - it's better not to use the macros SIGNAL and SLOT - they are error prone, like in your case. If you look inside them, they are generating a string, which could not be checked by compiler. Instead better to use following syntax:

```
QObject::connect(PtrLineedit1, &LineEditClass::clicked, this, &ThisClass::myslot);
```

Cause if you will write then:

```
QObject::connect(PtrLineedit1, &LineEditClass::Clicked, this, &ThisClass::myslot);
```

It would produce the error during compilation, in case when `LineEditClass::Clicked` is not defined. This would protect you from typos.

**UPD**: As eventually I've found another your question which faces issue  relevant to this one, I've updated this answer with more details, which might be helpful for others.

In case of overloaded methods, you must explicitly tell compiler which one should be used - for example we have following:

```
void QComboBox::currentIndexChanged(int index)
void QComboBox::currentIndexChanged(const QString &text)
```

thus the `&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged` could be resolved ambigously, and you will get the compilation error. To fix it you need to explicitly tell what are the arguments of the function you want to connect to:

```
QObject::connect(comboBox, static_cast<void(QComboBox::*)(int)>(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged), this, &ThisClass::myComboBoxSlotWithIntArg);
```

or

```
QObject::connect(comboBox, static_cast<void(QComboBox::*)(const QString &)>(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged), this, &ThisClass::myComboBoxSlotWithStringArg);
```

Comment: Its giving out an error saying non standard syntax, use & to create pointer to member. My syntax: QObject::connect(fileButton3, QToolButton::clicked, this, DynRefWizardPage::myslot); I have tried it on a tool button(filebutton3)

Comment: Hi its woking after using the below sysntax:QObject::connect(PtrLineedit1, &LineEditClass::Clicked, this, &ThisClass::myslot);

Comment: Oh... Very sorry - and thank you for pointing it out - one more example that nobody is protected from typos :) and using something that can prevent it is good idea (fixed it in my the answer).

Comment: The `SLOT`/`SIGNAL` macros can be quite useful especially if you want to indeed pass the name of the function you are calling (for example if the object and its connections are created through a settings file) instead of the address.

Comment: @rbaleksandar can't disagree, it all depends on the implemented architecture. There are even more trade-offs, like inability to use the default slot parameters. As for me this is kind of a point of a big discussion, what syntax to use when. So, mostly this answer is more a suggestion how to mitigate the problem that initially was faced - and for it the new syntax is a solution. P.S. I've never intended to say something like "NEVER use the SIGNAL/SLOT macros" :)